# How to use the typedef variables for int, float and char data types?

Tags: variables, types, typedef, enter

How can I write a C program explaining how to use the typedef variables for the following data types:

```
int   by name INT
float by name REAL
char  by name CHARACTER
```

The program allows the user to enter and print values of variables.

Comment: Show us how much you have tried.?

Comment: inline `#include<stdio.h>
<br/>
#include<conio.h>  
typedef int INT;  
typedef float REAL;  
typedef char CHARACTER;  
void main()  
{  
clrscr();  
printf("please enter integer NUM:\n");  
scanf("%d",&INT);  
printf("enter real NUM:\n");  
scanf("%f",&REAL);  
printf("enter letter:\n);  
scanf("%c",&CHARACTER);  
getch();  
}`